# Why doesn’t Shosanna try to kill Fredrick?

Tags: plot-explanation, inglourious-basterds

When Shosanna (as Emmanuelle) shot Fredrick down, she takes a quick look at the screen where she can see a scene with Fredrick (the actor). When she looks back at Fredrick, she recognizes that he still seems to be alive.

She then approaches him, but without any caution. As if she is concerned for his health.

Why is that?

She could have easily shot him again. Or did she run out of bullets? But even then she could have tried to smash his head with something lying around.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shosanna shot Fredrick **only** because he became a hindrance to her plot. Under different circumstances she wouldn't need to shoot Fredrick.

Fredrick is evidently quite besotted with Shosanna and time and again tries to vie for her attention. Even though Shosanna herself doesn't reciprocate those feelings, she nevertheless has a soft corner for him. So when Fredrick is on the floor, bleeding out from the bullet injuries she inflicted, she can't help but feel sorry for a *nice guy* who winds up in this unfortunate position.

P.S. I call Fredrick a nice guy because he was a compassionate human being. Notice that when his heroic act was made into a barbaric movie, it disturbed him so much that he walked out of the theater.

Answer (score 5):

I think she felt pity for him. As if she regretted what she did.

As you said, even running out of bullets wouldn't stop her from killing him another way, but that is ***if*** she definitely wanted to and I think that the answer here is no, at least later. She shot him at first because of her mission but she definitely felt something that stopped her from finishing the job and instead made her go there to help Fredrick.

Comment: +1 You can tell in her face that she felt guilt/regret/pity after shooting him. She only had to shoot him because he was getting in the way. It's a bit odd because he was a nazi war hero and she was there to kill nazi's, so why feel pity?

Comment: @DustinDavis: True, she was there to kill the Nazi's, Fredrick included. But she had not anticipated that she would need to _pull the trigger_ on a person who had been so friendly and affectionate to her. I have elaborated this point in [my answer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11642/why-doesnt-shosanna-try-to-kill-fredrick/11656#11656).

Comment: @DustinDavis Was Frederick a Nazi? She was there to kill the Nazi leadership, not random German soldiers.

Answer (score -2):

I think that zoller was an obstruction to the plan of shosanna's plan of killing nazis..and initially she saw him as one of them and still..but inside her was a soft corner for frederick..that's why she saw that whether zoller is alive or not..
Sidharth Iyer

Comment: In what way does this answer contribute anything the other two answers don't?